# Extend Backbone.Model from/with other non-Backbone object

Tags: javascript, inheritance, backbone.js, underscore.js

What I'm trying to achieve is extending a previously defined class with methods from `Backbone.Model` or the other way round, whatever works best. Basically my code looks like this:

```
var SomeObject = function() {};
SomeObject.CLASS_ATTRIBUTE = 'something';
SomeObject.prototype.aFunction = function() { return Math.E; };
SomeObject.prototype.attrB = 'wat';

var SomeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

At this point, how do I extend `SomeModel` with `SomeObject` (or the other way around) to contain `CLASS_ATTRIBUTE` as well as `aFunction`  and `attrB` being a Model attribute without loosing the `Backbone.Model` capabilities?

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

If `SomeObject` was defined as such:

```
var SomeObject = {
  CLASS_ATTRIBUTE: 'something',
  aFunction: function () { return MATH.E; },
  attrB: 'wat'
}
```

then

```
var SomeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
 // ...
});

_.extend(SomeModel.prototype, SomeObject);
```

would do what you required from it

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by extend?

1. Do you wish to merge your objects?
2. Do you wish to add custom "methods" to `SomeModel`?
3. Do you wish to create a NEW object that has both the methods and properties of `SomeModel` and `SomeObject`?

---

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tivie/jEXAg/)

---

```
var SomeObject = function() {};
SomeObject.CLASS_ATTRIBUTE = 'something';
SomeObject.prototype.aFunction = function() { return Math.E; };
SomeObject.prototype.attrB = 'wat';
var SomeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

// Merging instances of objects
var newSomeObject = new SomeObject(),
    newSomeModel = new SomeModel(),
    mergedObjects = $.extend(true, newSomeModel, newSomeModel);

console.log(mergedObjects);

// Prototyping
var mergedProto = $.extend(true, SomeModel.prototype, SomeObject.prototype);
console.log(mergedProto);

//factory
var myMergefactory = function() {
    var ret = $.extend(true, SomeModel.prototype, SomeObject.prototype);
    return ret;
}
```

As a note this is also valid...

```
var SomeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
SomeModel.CLASS_ATTRIBUTE = 'something';
SomeModel.prototype.aFunction = function() { return Math.E; };
SomeModel.prototype.attrB = 'wat';
```

or this...

```
var SomeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function (params) {
        $.extend(true, this, params.obj);
    }
});
var mObj = new SomeModel({obj: new SomeObject()});
```